# k8s istio-system firewall with different namespace

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, firewall, istio

i tried to create a firewall rule in k8s istio with "istio-system" ns, 
and i have a services within different ns. 
i need to create firewall rule with istio ingress that block all requests Besides "POST" requests.
i tried to create new rule in firewall like that:

```
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1 
kind: AuthorizationPolicy 
metadata: 
   name: deny-all
   namespace: istio-system  
spec: 
  {}
```

and that really block all the requests and after that i tried to apply this rule:

```
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1 
kind: AuthorizationPolicy 
metadata:  
  name: httpbin   
  namespace: test 
spec:  
  action: ALLOW  
  selector:    
    matchLabels: 
      app: test  
 rules:    
   to:
    - operation:
        hosts: ["https://ABCD.xxx.ddd"]
        methods: ["POST"]
        paths: ["/*"]
```

and that not successed 
To my current understanding, I can't block services that are on one namespace, 
using firewall rules as part of istio (within different ns) that is on another namespace. 
My question is is it possible to do this, and if so how?

Answer (score 1):

> i need to create firewall rule with istio ingress that block all requests Besides "POST" requests

Maybe just create one authorization policy which deny every single one of them besides POST?

---

I have made an example which does allow only GET requests and deny rest. Take a look.

```
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
  name: httpbin
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  action: DENY
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      istio: ingressgateway
  rules:
  - to:
    - operation:
        methods: ["POST", "HEAD", "PUT", "DELETE", "CONNECT", "OPTIONS", "TRACE", "PATCH"]
```

And some tests

```
root@httpbin-779c54bf49-s6g6r:/# curl http://xx.xx.xxx.xxx/productpage -X GET -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}\n"
200
root@httpbin-779c54bf49-s6g6r:/# curl http://xx.xx.xxx.xxx/productpage -X POST -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}\n"
403
root@httpbin-779c54bf49-s6g6r:/# curl http://xx.xx.xxx.xxx/productpage -X PUT -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}\n"
403
```

---

Related documentation about AuthorizationPolicy:

- https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/security/authorization-policy/
- https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/security/authorization/authz-http/
- https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/security/authorization/authz-deny/

---

Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: Istio best practice is to deny all and allow what you want to allow. But work, sure.

Answer (score 0):

My goal is to run a firewall that will block all requests coming from services that are not under the namespace of my organization.
For example: If my organization's services are under a namespace called "test", I expect any http request that comes in from an address that does not belong to that namespace to be blocked.
The point is this:
istio, which contains my firewall, is under a different namespace, meaning it is not under the namespace of my organization.
For example: istio sits under a namespace called "istio-system", and my services sit under a namespace called "test".
How can I block access to my services using a firewall under another namespace?
Note: Just for testing, I tried to put my firewall and my services in the same namespace, and still could not block access to my services.
What am I missing here, and what is the best way to exercise such a block?
this one blocked all http request:

```
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1 
kind: AuthorizationPolicy 
metadata: 
   name: deny-all
   namespace: istio-system  
spec: 
  {}
```

For example(in bottom code) - the example where I put istio-system name space and the services under the same namespace - and still could not block POST requests that are not from the services in my namespace:

```
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
 name: http
 namespace: test
spec:
 action: ALLOW
 selector:
   matchLabels:
     app: test
 rules:
 - from:
   - source:
       namespaces: ["test"]
   to:
   - operation:
       hosts: ["http://xxx.xxx.xxx"]
       methods: ["POST"]
```

Expected Behavior:
Post requests that are not in my namespace will be blocked
Current behavior:
Nothing is blocked